# Angular API Snapshot, Type 'IJobs' is not assignable to type 'IJobs[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I'm learning and try to build a jobboard in Angular 10.

My API setup works but when I go to my job detailpage chrome thrown:

ERROR in src/app/job-detail/job-detail.component.ts:49:74 - error TS2322: Type 'IJobs' is not assignable to type 'IJobs[]'.

49     this.dataService.getJobsDetail(field_custom_slug).subscribe( jobs => this.jobs = jobs )

src/app/job-detail/job-detail.component.ts:49:74 - error TS2740: Type 'IJobs' is missing the following properties from type 'IJobs[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

49     this.dataService.getJobsDetail(field_custom_slug).subscribe( jobs => this.jobs = jobs )

---

But I made an Interface file where I declare every field and the type of content it will be.

job-detail.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { dataService } from 'src/services/data.service';
import { JobapplyService } from 'src/services/jobapply.service';

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IJobs } from 'src/models/jobs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-job-detail',
  templateUrl: './job-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./job-detail.component.scss']
})

export class JobDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  jobs: IJobs[];

  isShow = false;

  FormData: FormGroup;
  showMsg: boolean = false;
 
  toggleDisplayForm() {
    document.getElementById("jobApply").scrollIntoView({behavior: "auto", block: 'start'});
  }

  onSubmit(FormData) {
    this.applyment.PostMessage(FormData)
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.showMsg = true;
      response
    });
  }

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private dataService: dataService,

    private builder: FormBuilder, 
    private applyment: JobapplyService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
    const field_custom_slug = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('field_custom_slug');

    this.dataService.getJobsDetail(field_custom_slug).subscribe( jobs => this.jobs = jobs )
    
    this.FormData = this.builder.group({
      fullname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])]),
      hremail: new FormControl(''),
      location: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      placeandcountry: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      linkedinurl: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      experience: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      hobbies: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      greatfit: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      resume: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      salary: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    })
  }

  

}
```

job-detail.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="jobs[0]">
    <section class="py-4 bg-light">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <a class="text-link" href="/"> home</a> <i class="fas fa-chevron-right mx-2"></i>
                    <a class="text-link" href="/jobs"> Jobs</a> <i class="fas fa-chevron-right mx-2"></i>
                    <a class="text-link" href="/jobs">{{ jobs[0].field_job_function }} at {{ jobs[0].field_company }}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="section-wrapper">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="row mb-5">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <figure class="figure">
                                <img [src]="['https://cryptojobs.world/' + jobs[0].field_logo]" width="100" height="100">                            
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <span class="d-block">
                                <small class="text-muted">Posted on : {{ jobs[0].created }}</small>
                            </span>
                            <h1 class="h1"></h1>
                            <h1 class="h1">{{ jobs[0].title }}</h1>

                            <h3 class="h3">{{ jobs[0].field_company }}</h3>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled d-flex">
                                <li *ngIf="jobs[0].field_is_remote" class="mr-1">{{ jobs[0].field_place }}</li>
                                <li *ngIf="jobs[0].field_is_remote" class="mx-1">|</li>
                                <li *ngIf="jobs[0].field_is_remote" class="mx-1">{{ jobs[0].field_country }}</li>
                                <li *ngIf="jobs[0].field_is_remote" class="mx-1">|</li>
                                <li *ngIf="!jobs[0].field_is_remote" class="mr-1">Remote</li>
                                <li *ngIf="!jobs[0].field_is_remote" class="mx-1">|</li>
                                <li class="ml-1">{{ jobs[0].field_job_type }}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="d-block my-3" />

                    <div class="mt-5" [innerHTML]="jobs[0].body"></div>
                    

                    <div class="card mt-3">
                        <div id="jobApply" class="card-footer">
                            <a *ngIf="!jobs[0].field_via_external" href="{{ jobs[0].field_external_apply }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Apply to this Job</a>
                            

                            <form class="mt-5" *ngIf="!jobs[0].field_via_form" [formGroup]="FormData" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(FormData.value)">
                                <div *ngIf="!showMsg == true"></div>
                                <h4>Applyment form</h4>

                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="fullname">Your Fullname</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" formControlName="fullname" required>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" formControlName="email" required>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                        <input type="hidden" class="d-none h-0" value="{{ jobs[0].field_hr_email }}" formControlName="hremail">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="location">Address</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="1234 Main St" formControlName="location" required>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="placeandcountry">Place and Country</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="placeandcountry" placeholder="Amsterdam, Netherlands" formControlName="placeandcountry" required>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                            <label for="linkedinurl">LinkedIn URL</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="linkedinurl" placeholder="https://linkedin.com/profile/link" formControlName="linkedinurl" required>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                            <label for="experience">How many years of experience do you have?</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="experience" placeholder="8 years" formControlName="experience" required>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                            <label for="hobbies">What kind of person are you, hobbies, family, your habits, maybe something funny?</label>
                                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="hobbies" placeholder="Tell something about yourself." formControlName="hobbies" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                            <label for="greatfit">Why are you a great fit for this job?</label>
                                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="greatfit" placeholder="" formControlName="greatfit" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="salary">Salary Expectation</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="salary" placeholder="Give us a number of annual expectation" formControlName="salary" required>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!FormData.valid">Submit</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                            <ng-container *ngIf="showMsg">
                                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                    Your submission send successfully to the HR manager of {{ jobs[0].field_company }}, are you ready for your next adverture?
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>

                            <div *ngIf="!jobs[0].field_via_form"><small><em>* We never save your personal information, this applyment send directly to the HR manager of the company and gets deleted from our database.</em></small></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="sticky-top pt-4">
                        <button *ngIf="!jobs[0].field_via_form" class="d-none d-md-block btn btn-primary btn-lg w-100" (click)="toggleDisplayForm()">Apply to this Job</button>
                        <a *ngIf="!jobs[0].field_via_external" href="{{ jobs[0].field_external_apply }}" target="_blank" class="d-none d-md-block btn btn-primary btn-lg w-100">Apply to this Job</a>

                        <div class="card mt-4">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="h4">Share this job</h4>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled d-flex socials">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://website.com/jobs/{{ jobs[0].field_custom_slug }}" target="_blank">
                                            <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="mx-2">
                                        <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Currentlyreading https://website.com/jobs/{{ jobs[0].field_custom_slug }}" title="Click to share this post on Twitter">
                                            <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://website.com/jobs/{{ jobs[0].field_custom_slug }}&title={{ jobs[0].title }} at {{ jobs[0].field_company }}&source=https://website.com/jobs/{{ jobs[0].field_custom_slug }}">
                                            <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
[image]

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `dataService.getJobsDetail(field_custom_slug)` return? Sounds like it's an array. If that's what you expect, then just change the type of your `jobs` variable to match.

Comment: I've updated the original post with an image; did console.log(this.dataService.getJobsDetail(field_custom_slug)); and that is actually my output.

Comment: @dutchsociety try `.subscribe( (jobs: IJobs[]) => this.jobs = jobs )`

Comment: @KamranKhatti why I already do this.jobs which is receiving jobs: IJobs[]; at like 18 of job-detail.component.ts.

Comment: @dutchsociety first try then I'll explain, also `console.log(jobs)` and share the output not the whole service like you did in above comments.

Comment: logging `getJobsDetail` is going to give you an observable. You'll need to do `this.dataService.getJobsDetail(field_custom_slug).subscribe(console.log)` to get the actual output from the observable.'

Answer (score 1):

It's look like your API is returning a simple IJob object and you're trying to assing that object into an array[].

Regards.

Comment: Can you help me further or give an example?

Comment: Your API is returning an simple object of IJob and you're trying to assign that simple object into an array og IJob objects. I think that's the problem. Check what's your API returning with a `console.log()`

Comment: Well indeed, the api is in array, and I take a snapshot from field_custom_slug and try to access that content again. Check the original post (image), there is what it returned..